# How can I make the most of a Barbarian's Rage?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, class-feature

I was subbing for a Barbarian player last night, and I realized just how few rages they get.  It seems they basically get one per daily power.  I also noticed that several of his powers had better effects when raging.  What can I do to make the most use of a Barbarian's rage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a strictly powergaming answer, of course, you save it for the biggest battle. The "rage-Boost" effect (by which your at-will powers and encounter powers are suddenly getting bonuses due to rage) means - **if your'e going to rage, do it as early in the combat as possible. Round 1 if possible.**

Second thing: You are a raging madman, but don't hold back from targeting skirmishers and minions when they get in your way. You get a bonus when you drop someone. You are a striker, but that doesn't mean you have to just go after the biggest bad-guy on the field every time.

If you just don't know when the "big encounter" is going to happen- let's say you are doing some general adventuring and don't have a specific villain you are hunting down..  (Which is common enough) **consider raging in round 1 of the very first encounter of the game just to sort of show off**, and establish your reputation. Your barbarian is still going to be a bad-ass.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this: one rage per combat; there's no reason to swap, generally. You want those bonus effects active as much as possible. And don't use Rage Strike for the same reason.